# Derived functors of torsion functor

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-functors

Let $A$ be a domain. For every $A$-module $M$ consider its torsion submodule $M^{tor}$ made up of elements of $M$ which are annihilated by a non zero-element of $A$. If $f \colon M \to N$ is a homomorphism, then $f(M^{tor}) \subseteq N^{tor}$, so call $f^{tor} \colon M^{tor} \to N^{tor}$ the induced map. We have a covariant functor $^{tor}$ from the category of $A$-modules to itself. It is straightforward to verify that $^{tor}$ is an additive left-exact functor; so we can consider its right-derived functors $R^i$, for $i \geq 0$: if $Q^{\bullet}$ is an injective resolution of $M$, then $R^i(M) = H^i((Q^{\bullet})^{tor})$.

If $A$ is a PID then it is quite easy to compute $R^i(M)$ for finite $A$-module $M$, because it is easy to have injective resolutions. In fact it is well-known that $K$ and $K/A$ are injective $A$-modules, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $A$.

My questions are:

1. Can one compute $R^i(M)$ if $A$ is not a PID or $M$ is not finite? Have these functors been studied?
2. What is the relation between $R^i$ and $\mathrm{Tor}_j$?
3. In the category of $A$-modules, are there other derived functors that have been studied and that are not $\mathrm{Tor}$ nor $\mathrm{Ext}$?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may wish to read about [local cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_cohomology). The Wikipedia article is mostly about the sheaf theory,  but over an affine scheme and for quasicoherent sheaves, you can think of it as follows: if $R$ is a ring (say, noetherian), $I \subset R$ an ideal, then for an $R$-module $M$,  $H^i_I(M)$ is the right-derived functor of the functor $M \mapsto \varinjlim \hom_R(R/I^m, M)$; this sends a module $M$ to its collection of $I$-torsion elements. (The interpretation of $I$-torsion and global sections supported along the subscheme cut out by $I$ gives the connection between this discussion and the sheaf theoretic formulation.) So, since the derived functor of $\hom$ is $\mathrm{Ext}$, a little abstract nonsense shows that $H^i_I(M)$ can be described as $\varinjlim \mathrm{Ext}^i(R/I^m, M)$. (It seems more natural for these functors to be related to $\mathrm{Ext}$ than to $\mathrm{Tor}$, since to obtain the torsion in a module, you are looking for maps *into* the module, not elements of the tensor product.

Let's say that $R$ is a local ring and $I$ the maximal ideal. Then, the local cohomology modules are exactly the torsion modules you ask about. If $R$ is regular, they can be computed using the local duality isomorphism $H^i_I(M) = (\mathrm{Ext}^{n-i}(M, k))^{\vee}$ (where $\vee$ denotes the Matlis dual, $n$ the dimension, and $k$ the residue field; see SGA 2, exp. V). So if you know a *projective* resolution for $M$, you can use that to compute the local cohomology groups (usually, a projective resolution is much easier to find than an injective one!).

Comment: It looks like chapter 7 of the book *[Twenty-four hours of local cohomology](http://books.google.com/books?id=5HgmUQsbe5sC&pg=PA77)* by Iyengar et al. is very readable and gives some basic tools for calculating local cohomology.

Comment: There is a global version of the Matlis-duality called the Greenlees-May duality, which allows you to compute local cohomology over any noetherian rings (and even somethimes over non-noetherian rings, provided the ideal in question is nice enough).

Comment: Actually, you don't need a resolution to compute local cohomology. If $A$ is a noetherian ring, and $I$ is an ideal in $A$, and $K$ is the infinite Koszul complex associated to $I$, then the derived torsion functor of any complex $M$ (no bounded assumptions) is given by $R\Gamma_I M \cong M\otimes_A K$.

Answer (score 7):

**For 3:** This is almost cheating, I know...

Mac Lane studied the functors $\mathrm{Trip}_n$ which arise from derivating (?) the functor $M\otimes N\otimes P$ of *three* variables. There are references in his book *Homology*. The interesting thing is, this cannot be expressed in terms of $\mathrm{Tor}$.

**For 1:** If $\mathcal I$ is the set of all non-zero ideals ordered by inclusion (which is directed), we have $$M^{tors}=\varinjlim_{I\in\mathcal I}\:\hom_A(A/I,M).$$ You should look up the relationship between right-deriving , and directed direct limits like this one, and that should tell you what your $R^i$ functors are. (This will tell you that your $R^i$ are more related to $\mathrm{Ext}$ than to $\mathrm{Tor}$)