# torsion modules of short exact sequences

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Consider an integral domain $R$ and a short exact sequence of left-modules
$$
0\rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0.
$$

I want to understand the relation between their torsion sub-modules. I want to understand what is the next term of the following sequence
$$
0\rightarrow A_{tor} \rightarrow B_{tor} \rightarrow C_{tor} \rightarrow ??
$$

Comment: This answer seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60762/derived-functors-of-torsion-functor
In particular, under certain conditions, a left exact functor can be right-derived and induces a long exact sequence. Let $T$ denote the functor $T(M) = M^{\text{tor}}$. Then we obtain a long exact sequence
$0 \to T(A) \to T(B) \to T(C) \to R^1T(A) \to R^2T(B) \to \cdots$.
Unfortunately, it is beyond my scope to say anything useful about these conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the commutative case, let $K$ be the fraction field of $R$. Then you have for any module $A$, an exact sequence $0\to A_{\mathrm{tor}}\to A\to A\otimes_R K\to A_1\to 0$, where $A_1$ is defined by the above sequence. Then, by snake lemma, you get an exact sequence, $0\to A_{\mathrm{tor}}\to B_{\mathrm{tor}}\to C_{\mathrm{tor}}\to A_1\to B_1\to C_1\to 0$.